# How do I get hypervisor to run?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, hypervisor

I'm trying to get Windows Sandbox and/or a hyper-v VM to run on my Windows 10 Education. I already followed all the advises I could find on the net:

1. Support is enabled in the BIOS (i.e SVM Mode is set to enabled) and the Task Manager confirms this.

[image: task manager]

2. Virtual Machine PLatform and Windows Hypervisor Platform as well as Hyper-V are installed in the windows feature installations.

[image: Windows features]

3. The hypervisorlaunchtype is set to Auto and running bcdedit confirms this.

[image: bcdedit]

Yet when I try to either start a Windows Sandbox or run a VM, windows complains that the hypervisor is not running.
Since the boot configuration data (BCD) is involved and apparently starting the hypervisor before the OS itself is started seems to be a key to getting it to work I have a sneaking suspicion that my unusual drive/boot setup might be the culprit. I have two identical SSDs with a 150GB mirrored system partition and the remaining 780GB being a striped volume. To this end I tried to mirror as much of the system critical parts (MBR, EFI, Recovery partition) as possible and as far as I can tell, I've been successful, though I can't rule out that certain parts of it are not kept mirrored and might now throw a wrench into my efforts. This is my partition setup:

[image: diskmgr]
[image: diskpart]

Am I thinking too complicated? What else could be the problem or if it is the mirroring, how can I fix it?

Update:
Here's a screenshot of the relevant bit of the systeminfo output.

[image: systeminfo]

Comment: If you're getting a "hypervisor not running" error then it's not related to your disk setup. Please make sure your CPU supports SLAT (separate feature from VMX).

Comment: I'm using an AMD 5800X CPU so I'm fairly sure it supports SLAT. Googling for SLAT I found the recommendation to use the systeminfo command to check for compatibility and that too suggests that everything should work.

Comment: @SamForbis I don't claim to be an expert in this area, but since Hyper-V is a Type 1 hypervisor, and (once enabled) it starts up *before* Windows, why couldn't disk configuration be a reason that Hyper-V startup could fail?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds To be honest, I'm not actually sure if it could prevent Hyper-V from starting or not. I just think it's unlikely.

Comment: Just to be sure, you haven't installed any other virtualization software like Virtual Box or Android Development tools that use virtualization?

Comment: No other virtualization software is installed.